# DALI interface to 3.3v

Tags: circuit-design, dali

I'm trying to make a circuit to interface a DALI driver (Digitally Addressable Lighting Interface) to a SAML21 microcontroller. 
Voltages on the DALI side goes from 0 to 22.5V, a digital 0 goes from 0-6.5V and a digital 1 from 9.5-22.5 V. 
So my goal is to translate DALI 0s and 1s to 3.3v levels.
DALI- terminal is connected directrly to GND and DALI+ is connected to a pull-up resistor to 12v power supply. So with a simple transistor to GND I get to control DALI+ to go from 12v (aprox) to 0.4v (aprox) by switching the transistor.
The hard part comes when I need to translate from DALI to 3.3v, because of the different possible voltages.
Could you give me some directions as to how to approach this part of the circuit?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, look for microcontroller application notes how to build a DALI interface. They do it properly with isolation.

Comment: Page2: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa422a/slaa422a.pdf?ts=1605771162892

Comment: Thanks, I will start with that :D

Comment: Don't connect DALI- to your micro's 0V, use a diode bridge for polarity insensitivity. It used to be optional but is now mandatory to be polarity insensitive, unless your device is or contains a DALI PSU.

Comment: I've been studying the pdf @WesleyLee provided, and I think that it is for the led driver side of the dali communication, the slave side I mean. Am I correct?
I see that the DALI+ and DALI- terminals are simply connected to each other through  resistor-led-solid relay. Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: I was not reading it correctly. The design is for the master DALI, but I have another question now: considering that DALI+ and DALI- are completly isolated from the circuit, who provides power to those lines?
Does the master needs an isolated power supply for the DALI lines, or where does the power comes from? 
I appreciate the help you gave me :D

Comment: @IvánGerber Happy to help but not in the comments on this question. You now have a completely different question to the original so it needs posting seperately.